# Why I am getting cursor statement in the output?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am learning **PL/SQL** and I fired this query in the SQL Command Line

```
SELECT DNAME, CURSOR(SELECT SALARY, COMMISSSION_PCT 
                     FROM  EMP e 
                     WHERE e.did=101) 
from dept d 
order by dname;

DNAME                                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURSOR(SELECTSALARY,                                                            
--------------------                                                            
AI                                                                              
CURSOR STATEMENT : 2                                                            

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

    SALARY COMMISSSION_PCT                                                      
---------- ---------------                                                      
     12000              .3                                                      
     19000              .5                                                      
     10000              .4                                                      


Nano_tech                                                                       
CURSOR STATEMENT : 2                                                            

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2
```

Why am I getting **CURSOR STATEMENT:2** while I have more than 2 tuples in the database? I know cursor acts like a pointer in PL/SQL but shouldn't it return 3 rather than 2?

Answer (score 4):

The "2" in

> CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

emitted by SQL*Developer is telling you that the cursor is in the 2nd column of your query output.  ***It is NOT implying that the cursor's results contain 2 rows.***

Replace your query with this:

```
SELECT DNAME, 'XXX' DUMMY, CURSOR(SELECT SALARY, COMMISSSION_PCT 
                           FROM  EMP e 
                           WHERE e.did=101) 
from dept d 
order by dname;
```

And SQL*Developer will start emitting "CURSOR STATEMENT: 3".